# "-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object" when calling selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to change the current selection of a NSTableView with the following code:

```
[self.modesTable selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

I'm not using any dictionary at all. Anybody knows where this might come from?

Here's the stack trace:

```
2012-04-03 18:14:00.598 TurnMode[7130:403] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-04-03 18:14:00.599 TurnMode[7130:403] -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
2012-04-03 18:14:00.603 TurnMode[7130:403] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ac44fc6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8644cd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ac44dfa +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ac44d84 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ac01ec0 -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 96
    5   TurnMode                            0x0000000100009722 -[FRRMode saveObject:named:] + 210
    6   TurnMode                            0x0000000100008f20 -[FRRMode saveToUserDefaults] + 192
    7   TurnMode                            0x000000010000701d -[FRRPreferencesController tableViewSelectionDidChange:] + 125
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff877b7d32 __-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_1 + 47
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8abedaaa _CFXNotificationPost + 2634
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff877a3fe7 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 65
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bcd51d9 -[NSTableView _sendSelectionChangedNotificationForRows:columns:] + 203
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bcabbfe -[NSTableView _enableSelectionPostingAndPost] + 425
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bcd4045 -[NSTableView _doSelectIndexes:byExtendingSelection:indexType:funnelThroughSingleIndexVersion:] + 2915
    14  TurnMode                            0x0000000100006662 -[FRRPreferencesController syncViewWithTempModel] + 914
    15  TurnMode                            0x0000000100006c76 -[FRRPreferencesController showPreferencesView:] + 438
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ac3475d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bc6ecb2 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bd5bfe7 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 399
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bd5bd1e -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 125
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bff9dd4 -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 38
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8be8a3a9 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 138
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bcd5b4b NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 339
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d6f4294 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1263
    24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d6f38a0 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 446
    25  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d70a677 SendEventToEventTarget + 76
    26  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d7506c1 _ZL18SendHICommandEventjPK9HICommandjjhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 398
    27  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d837c59 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 56
    28  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d87e73d SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 253
    29  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d7497bb _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 101
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d877175 _ZL19PopUpMenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdS1_tjPK4RecttjS4_S4_PK10__CFStringPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 1660
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d877434 _HandlePopUpMenuSelection7 + 621
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8be8d075 _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 3860
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2386b6 _NSPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 39
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8be8b1da -[NSCarbonMenuImpl popUpMenu:atLocation:width:forView:withSelectedItem:withFont:withFlags:withOptions:] + 322
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c0eb8da +[NSStatusBarButtonCell popupStatusBarMenu:inRect:ofView:withEvent:] + 673
    36  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c0ebb85 -[NSStatusBarButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 147
    37  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bc6cbde -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
    38  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bc376e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
    39  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c0ec598 -[NSStatusBarWindow sendEvent:] + 66
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bbd016d -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bb661f2 -[NSApplication run] + 555
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bde4b88 NSApplicationMain + 867
    43  TurnMode                            0x0000000100001ab2 main + 34
    44  TurnMode                            0x0000000100001a84 start + 52
)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace printed when the exception is thrown?

Comment: The stack trace indicates that the problem is likely in either `-[FRRMode saveToUserDefaults]` or `-[FRRMode saveObject:name:]`. Can you post the code for those methods? 

For your own debugging, make sure you've set an exception breakpoint so that the debugger stops when this exception is thrown, then click on the relevant lines in the stack trace to find exactly which line in your code is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is definitely caused by calling `-[NSDictionary setObject:forKey:]` in `-[FRRMode saveObject:named:]`.

If you are indeed not using any dictionaries in this method, you should still look for `setObject:forKey:`. If you over-release an object, its memory address may be occupied by an `NSDictionary` which obviously does not respond to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that -[FRRPreferencesController syncViewWithTempModel] is your method which is calling [self.modesTable selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO].  Then, the table view dutifully changes its selection.

It also appears that your FRRPreferencesController object is an observer of the notification posted by the table view when its selection changes.  That, in turn, calls -[FRRMode saveToUserDefaults] which calls -[FRRMode saveObject:named:] and that is trying to mutate an immutable dictionary.

From the name saveToUserDefaults, I wonder if you're grabbing a dictionary-typed value from NSUserDefaults and then trying to mutate it.  NSUserDefaults does not hold or return mutable collections, even if you pass a mutable collection into its -setObject:forKey:.  When you later retrieve it, you get an immutable copy.